# how to find all folders under directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I tested find all folders under a directory with the environment of visual studio using mfc. Simply make a mfc dlg, add a button, paste the code below. The only variable to give is "product_path" directory with folders, empty folder is ok name like 123,or abc, or ABC. 
Testing:
  test 1 folders named 123,456.
         result:can be found all. 
  test 2 folders named 123,456,ab. 
         result:the folder name ab can not found. 
  test 3 folders named 123,ab,AB.
         result:the folder name AB can not found.

```
/*vector_folder_name used to store found folders*/
vector<CString> vector_folder_name;
/*product_path directory with folders*/
CString product_path=_T("..\\ProductType");
//sprintf(product_path,"..\\%s","ProductType");
if (product_path.Right(1) != "\\")
{
    product_path += _T("\\");
}       
product_path += _T("*.*");
CFileFind ff;

BOOL ret = ff.FindFile(product_path);
while (ret)
{
    ret = ff.FindNextFile();
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        if (ff.IsDirectory() && !ff.IsDots())
        {
            //CString path = ff.GetFilePath();
            CString folder_name = ff.GetFileName();
            vector_folder_name.push_back(folder_name);

            //TraverseDir(path, vec);
        }
        //else /*if(!ff.IsDirectory() && !ff.IsDots())*/
        //{
        //  CString name = ff.GetFileName();
        //  CString path = ff.GetFilePath();
        //  vector_folder_name.push_back(path);
        //}
    }
}
//sort(vector_folder_name.begin(),vector_folder_name.end());
sort(vector_folder_name.begin(),vector_folder_name.end(),compare1);

ff.Close(); // do not foget close
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what your folder looks like and the program output?

Comment: Maybe you are using `CString::Compare` to compare folder names. Use `CString::CompareNoCase` instead.

Comment: We need a [mcve] here.

Comment: empty folder is ok. My folder like 123,abc,ABC

Comment: make a mfc and a button can run this code.

Comment: The problem most likely is to be found in the code you are not showing, that is the comparator `compare1`.

Comment: @zett42 no, the problem is within his code, see answer below.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I see. I never remember weird behaviour of `CFileFind` which differs from logic of underlying API `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile`. My suggestion to OP, replace `CFileFind` by [`std::directory_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) if available. Makes the code much cleaner.

Comment: The question is on hold. I have try to reedit. whan can I do other thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is totally unrelated to uppercase or lower case file names, and there is nothing magic about the situation, but your code is incorrect. It's also unrelated to the `compare1` function

[`FindNextFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfilefind-class#findnextfile) returns `FALSE` upon the last file found and therefore your code simply skips the last file found.

In other words if `FindNextFile` returns `FALSE`, it's not an error but it means that you've got the *last* file in the directory.

This (even simpler) code works:

```
  ...
  BOOL ret = ff.FindFile(product_path);
  while (ret)
  {
    ret = ff.FindNextFile();
    if (ff.IsDirectory() && !ff.IsDots())
    {
      // it's a directory
      CString folder_name = ff.GetFileName();
      vector_folder_name.push_back(folder_name);
    }
  }
  ...
```

I've removed your outcommented code.

Comment: Big thx to  Michael Walz. The problems solved.

Comment: Ok,sorry for forgot it.